# Require extending classes to listen to changes in abstract class javaFX properties

Tags: event-handling, javafx-8, abstract-class

I want to build an abstract class, and I want to specify certain JavaFX properties to be listened/handled by the extending classes. For example, I have:

-abstract class CircleX that has a layoutXProperty...

Then I make:
class MyCircle extends CircleX

I want to make sure that MyCircle implements a 
layoutXProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener....)

I know I can make abstract methods that need to be overridden. but is there a way to be specific about what variables those methods should operate on, handle?

Comment: Do you mean "I want to make sure that `MyCircle` ***calls*** `layoutProperty().addListener(...)`"? The `addListener` method is presumably implemented in whatever class `layoutXProperty` is an instance of (I'm guessing some `Property<?>` implementation).

Comment: I guess yea--I am a bit uclear on the terminology . The end result is that I want MyCircle to handle changes in layoutXProperty. Sorry if I am not clear (I am trying to learn this as I go--don't have clear preconceived ideas of the how all of this works..)

Comment: just realized. I can just provide the methods anyway, and make then overridable by removing the "final" tag. Right?

Comment: That last comment is a true statement, but I don't really understand what you are asking.

Comment: ok will rephrase my question. Is there a way to make sure/require that MyCircle provides a listener to a property from CircleX?

Comment: If circleX extends [ObservableValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html) then it has an method [addListener()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html#addListener-javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener-) to which you can pass a ChangeListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public abstract class CircleX {

    private final DoubleProperty layoutX ;

    public CircleX() {
        layoutX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        layoutX.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) ->
            layoutXUpdated(oldValue, newValue));
    }

    public abstract void layoutXUpdated(Double oldLayoutX, Double newLayoutX) ;

    public DoubleProperty layoutXProperty() {
        return layoutX ;
    }

    public final double getLayoutX() {
        return layoutXProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setLayoutX(double layoutX) {
        layoutXProperty().set(layoutX);
    }
}
```

Here you add a listener in the superclass that invokes an abstract method. Then any subclass must implement the abstract method, and that method is invoked when the property changes.

Comment: yes, this looks like it is the solution I am trying to find.

Comment: @James_D: If a class includes abstract methods, then the class itself must be declared abstract.